# Front-End User Profile

Tags: custom-field, uploads, users, user-meta, front-end

I have a front end user profile template I am working on, and everything is working fine except for upload a profile picture. I have a custom user field created and I am trying to use the button file type to upload the picture and store the URL in my custom field.

Take a look -
https://pastebin.com/rPErwCgU

I'm currently already using this code for my front end post upload, it allows multiple pictures. I need to figure out how to do this for a user with only 1 photo and storing it in a custom field attached to the current user --

```
if (!empty($_FILES['sightMulti']['tmp_name'][0])) {
    $i = 1;
    $files = $_FILES['sightMulti'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("sight" . $i => $file);
            $newuploadMulti = sight("sight" . $i, $pid);
            if ($i == 1) {
                update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $newuploadMulti);
            }
            add_post_meta($pid, 'imic_property_sights', $newuploadMulti, false);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The field in the form --

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <label><?php _e('Upload Images', 'framework'); ?></label>
        <p><?php _e('Upload images that are best clicked for better appearance of your property', 'framework'); ?></p> 
</div>
<div class="row" id="multiplePhotos" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <?php
        echo'<div class="image-placeholder" id="photoList">';
        if (!empty($property_sights_value)) {
            foreach ($property_sights_value as $property_sights) {
                $default_featured_image = get_post_meta($Property_Id, '_thumbnail_id', true);
                if ($default_featured_image == $property_sights) {
                    $def_class = 'default-feat-image';
                } else {
                    $def_class = '';
                }
                echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">';
                echo '<div id="property-img"><div id="property-thumb" class="' . $def_class . '"><a id="feat-image" class="accent-color default-image" data-original-title="Set as default image" data-toggle="tooltip" style="text-decoration:none;" href="#"><div class="property-details" style="display:none;"><span class="property-id">' . $Property_Id . '</span><span class="thumb-id">' . $property_sights . '</span></div><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($property_sights) . '" class="image-placeholder" id="filePhoto2" alt=""/></a>';
                if (get_query_var('site')) {
                    echo '<input rel="' . $Property_Id . '" type="button" id="' . $property_sights . '" value="Remove" class="btn btn-sm btn-default remove-image">';
                }
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
        <input id="filePhotoMulti" type="file" name="sightMulti[]" multiple onChange="previewMultiPhotos();">
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I have right up top with the rest of my fields that save fine -

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['agent-image'] ) )
update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'agent_image', esc_attr( $_POST['agent-image'] ) );

if(!empty($_FILES)) {
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();

$file = $_FILES[agent-image];

$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );

move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );

$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
}
```

My input field --

```
<input type="file" name="agent-image">
```

How I'm using it on the author.php template --

```
<?php 
$author_pic = get_the_author_meta('agent-image', $user->ID);
echo '<div><img src="'. $author_pic .'" alt="'. $userName .'" class="img-thumbnail authppic"></div>'; ?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Code is now causing that page to give me a HTTP 500 error --

```
if ( !empty( $_FILES[agent-image][name] )) {
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();

$file = $_FILES[agent-image];

$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );

move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );

$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'agent_image', $attach_id ));
}
```

Comment: Where or how do you process the file information after the input?

Comment: There is no code to handle the input 'agent-image'?

Comment: sorry bro, but the code you linked is a miss and contain many deprecated WordPress code,
you can check this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/frontend-image-uploading-from-edit-profile-page-goldenapples) to add front end user profile

Comment: questions should be self contained, not ask people to go round the web to try to understand what is it you are asking.... assuming you are intrested in a useful answer :(

Comment: he is asking about front end not admin

Comment: sorry for that mistake ,i update my answer =>thanks bro :-)

Comment: @ChristineCooper It's a lot of code so I used pastebin.

Comment: @lukgoh No and that's what I'm missing

Comment: @MarkKaplun Not sure what you mean, but my question is pretty straightforward. I have a form with everything working except the image upload and I need to know how to fix it.

Comment: if it is straight forward why do people need to go to another site to learn what it is?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a miss", but the code I have everything works fine and as should EXCEPT the user profile upload.

Comment: try review deprecated WordPress code and review html div's , see if it helped

Comment: Please enable debugging then try to develop something. your code full of errors. try with latest WordPress and enable debug. After cleaning your code update your question. then someone might help you.

Comment: thanks but right now im just interested in the image upload.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments, you might want to learn how you do things like create meta boxes and do a file upload in Wordpress without using a framework like CMB2 first. However, as a seasoned Wordpress developer, I have found that using CMB2 greatly increased my productivity.

I highly recommend using [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) to create a front end form for editing a user profile. I just did the same thing and I modified the code from these links:

- https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Bringing-Metaboxes-to-the-Front-end
- https://webdevstudios.com/2015/03/30/use-cmb2-to-create-a-new-post-submission-form/

You have 3 functions (function names are from the second linked article above):
One registers the cmb2 fields

```
function wds_frontend_form_register() {
//code..
}
```

One create a shortcode for displaying the form:

```
function wds_do_frontend_form_submission_shortcode( $atts = array() ) {
//code..
}
```

and the third handles the submission of the form:

```
function wds_handle_frontend_new_post_form_submission( $cmb, $post_data = array() ) {
//code..
}
```

You can easily update your user instead of inserting a post here with [wp_update_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) and [update_user_meta().](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Full code examples are available through the links. [CMB2 field types reference docs here](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types). [Link to file field type (allowing image upload)](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#file).

This linked [example-functions.php](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/blob/master/example-functions.php#L530) also has an example for editing user profile fields (but this automatically hooks into the admin side). Handy if you also want to add fields there.

Good luck. I really recommend [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) it is brilliant.

Comment: use a plugin is rarely a good answer around here as it teaches nothing

Comment: @MarkKaplun it is a library not a plugin and I think a lot of people would disagree with you in this case. Have you even looked at it? CMB2 is the main competitor of ACF which is one the defacto ways of doing advanced fields in Wordpress. It is well written, organised, supported, builds on existing WP api. Can't see why no one would be learning here.

Comment: and it is bloated way over the needs of answering this simple question. There should be a very good reason to add 10k lines of code to your theme where 50 would have been enough

Comment: There might be a context where using CMB2 is a very good idea. I use it in pretty much every single large scale, professional WP project I do because it is so useful. Not every example on this forum has to be the most simple, smallest lines of code / use case. Code is all about building on the foundations of others. Still don't see why this isn't a valid contribution.

Comment: there is no reason to use either CMB2, ACF or whatever. writing metaboxes is easy and it just makes your life harder when the libraries limit you.

Comment: If there was no reason for them, then why do they exist and having a consistent following? Just because you think there is a right way of doing something yourself, doesn't mean you should restrict all the possible ways of doing something. I advocate adding as many possible ways of solving the problem, then the best ones can be upvoted.

Comment: average wordpress development is done by people that think that putting some plugins and configuring them is development. As I said in the first comment, the answers here should be aimed at people that want to develop their own solution. There is nothing wrong in being an "integrator" but people at some point need to be able to do this by themselves otherwise the integrators will not have plugins and themes to work with.

Comment: @MarkKaplun feel free to go over to the CMB2 forums and express your views. There will always be people who think they should build everything from scratch. I agree everyone should learn the fundamentals first, but is this forum only about fundamentals of Wordpress?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66929/discussion-between-andrew-welch-and-mark-kaplun).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !empty( $_FILES[agent-image][name] ) ) {

                $file = $_FILES[agent-image];

                $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('action' => 'tm_about_you' ) );

                if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {

                  return false;

                } else {

                    $filename = $file_return['file'];

                    $attachment = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                        'post_content'   => '',
                        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                        'guid' => $file_return['url']
                    );

                    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );

                    // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
                    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

                    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'agent_image', $attachment_id ));

                }

            }
```

Comment: Im already doing something similar for my front end posts. I've updated my question.

Comment: how does this apply to my situation?

Comment: At the time I posted this I commented on your question saying you didn't have any code to handle the file upload on the front end, you responded with: "that's the problem" so I gave you the code?

Comment: Ok what I meant is how can this be used as an answer to my question.

Comment: Oh sorry, so change this: $_FILES[featured_image]; to what ever your input name is set to. Then replace:  

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

set_post_thumbnail( $page, $attach_id );

With adding the file to your custom field.

Comment: What do you mean with adding the file to my custom field?

Comment: use the update_user_meta(); to update their avatar or use add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ); to store it in a custom field for that user.

Comment: I still cant get it to work, I updated my question with code that I tried.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code and it's giving me a http 500 error on that page. I updated my question with the code I used.

Comment: Try that... updated.

Comment: same results :(

Comment: Can you turn on debug mode from the config file and tell me what error you are getting? Also I just noticed you need to change this: array('action' => 'tm_about_you' ) (the tm_about_you part) to your function name.

Comment: what tm part are you referring to? I dont see it

Comment: The third line:

$file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('action' => 'tm_about_you' ) );